# Couldn't match expected type 'MultTree b' with '[MultTree b]'

Tags: haskell, syntax, tree, zipwith

I'm relatively new to Haskell.

I'm trying to create a **function** `zipWithMult :: (a -> b -> c) -> MultTree a -> MultTree b -> MultTree c` that behaves similar to the function `zipWith` for lists. It should combine the two input trees using the given function of type `a -> b -> c`.

**MultTree** represents non-empty trees whose nodes may have arbitrary many children:

```
data MultTree a = MultNode a [MultTree a] deriving Show
```

For example, when i have the following two trees:

```
t1 :: MultTree Integer
t1 = MultNode 8 [MultNode 3 [MultNode (-56) [], MultNode 4 [], MultNode 987 []], MultNode 4 [MultNode 6 []]]

t2 :: MultTree Integer
t2 = MultNode (-2) [MultNode 5 [MultNode 16 [], MultNode 7 []], MultNode (-9) [MultNode 1 [], MultNode 5 []]]
```

The application of the function `zipWithMult (+) t1 t2` should result in:

```
MultNode 6 [MultNode 8 [MultNode (-40) [], MultNode 11 []], MultNode (-5) [MultNode 7 []]]
```

Nodes that have no corresponding node in the other tree should be simply dropped.

**What i have so far:**

```
zipWithMult :: (a -> b -> c) -> MultTree a -> MultTree b -> MultTree c
zipWithMult f (MultNode x []) (MultNode y ys) = MultNode (f x y) []
zipWithMult f (MultNode x xs) (MultNode y []) = MultNode (f x y) []
zipWithMult f (MultNode x xs) (MultNode y ys) = MultNode (f x y) (zipWithMult f xs ys)
```

I don't understand why i get this error for my third exression in `zipWithMult`

```
Couldn't match expected type `MultTree b'
              with actual type `[MultTree b]'
* In the third argument of `zipWithMult', namely `ys'
  In the second argument of `MultNode', namely
    `(zipWithMult f xs ys)'
  In the expression: MultNode (f x y) (zipWithMult f xs ys)
```

I feel like i did a mistake with the syntax in Haskell, but i'm not sure.

Comment: `zipWithMult` returns a simple `MultTree`, so for `MultNode (f x y) (zipWithMult f xs ys)` we have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zipWithMult` returns a simple `MultTree`, so for `MultNode (f x y) (zipWithMult f xs ys)` we have a problem.

You can work with [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) to process two lists (the items of the first and second parameter), and return this as a list of `MultTree`s:

```
zipWithMult :: (a -> b -> c) -> MultTree a -> MultTree b -> MultTree c
zipWithMult f (MultNode x xs) (MultNode y ys)
    = MultNode (f x y) (zipWith (zipWithMult f) xs ys)
```

For the given sample data, we then obtain:

```
Prelude> zipWithMult (+) t1 t2
MultNode 6 [MultNode 8 [MultNode (-40) [],MultNode 11 []],MultNode (-5) [MultNode 7 []]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean answer! I understand it now